# doubletap not working in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara

I am working on cucumber, and facing problem on double click event.
I need double click on table row.
Tried on many ways not success.

```
element = page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="user_test"]/tbody/tr')
page.driver.browser.mouse.double_click(element.native)
```

Then

```
page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="user_test"]/tbody/tr').double_click
```

MY scenario is on tr click a dialog box get open.
Any help from anybody.

Comment: I am feeling you have some css overlay over that tr. That's why its not clickable..

Comment: Give details on what errors you're getting, and the JS that's supposed to trigger the desired behavior

Comment: No error,it shows tr getting click but as a result on doubleclick dialog box should open...
I have tried and found that doubleclick just working as singleclick..

Comment: Ok I got the exact problem. I am using double_click but in actual js doubletap is use.. is there any method to use double tab in cucumber, because it wont work directly like "element.double_click"

Please help.

Comment: capybara doesn't provide any touch methods, however there are some gems that claim to add support for some drivers, like https://github.com/Ricardonacif/touch_action - I haven't used them so can't vouch for any of them.  Also, please change the title of this question since it's not really about double_click

Answer (score 1):

Since your comments have indicated the JS is actually responding to a doubletap and not double_click - Capybara doesn't provide any touch actions.  There are addons that purport to add support for touch events to some of Capybaras drivers, such as https://github.com/Ricardonacif/touch_action that may provide what you need (depending on what driver you're using, etc)